# How to make DHT22 readings more reliable?

Tags: c++, linux, gpio

I'm reading from DHT22 temperature/humidity sensor in C++ application on Linux (Armbian Bookworm on RockPiS board). I control GPIO using the IOCTL+poll/read interface and it works most of the time and I get the correct temperature/humidity readings. The example code follows:

```
            // request rising edge events
        struct gpioevent_request eventreq = { 0 };
        eventreq.lineoffset = m_line;
        eventreq.handleflags = GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_INPUT;
        eventreq.eventflags = GPIOEVENT_REQUEST_RISING_EDGE;
        strcpy(eventreq.consumer_label, "DHT22");

        if (ioctl(m_fd, GPIO_GET_LINEEVENT_IOCTL, &eventreq) == -1) {
            trace("DHT22: Error setting the line event (%d)\n", errno);
            break;
        }

        uint64_t reading = 0;
        uint64_t last_timestamp = 0;

        while (m_running) {
            // wait for rising edge
            struct pollfd pfd = { 0 };
            pfd.fd = eventreq.fd;
            pfd.events = POLLIN;
            int ret = poll(&pfd, 1, 1); // 1 millisecond timeout (= end of reading)

            if (ret == -1) {
                trace("DHT22: Error while polling event from GPIO (%d)\n", errno);
            }
            else if (pfd.revents & POLLIN) {
                // rising edge
                struct gpioevent_data event_data;
                read(eventreq.fd, &event_data, sizeof(event_data));

                // ... processing of data here ...
            }
            else if (ret == 0) {
                // timeout
                // ... finalizing the data here ...
            }
        }
```

The problem lies in the situation when there is higher CPU usage from another application. Then the readings are not occasionally read correctly but still works in 80% of cases which is sufficient for our purpose. I think the problem lies in the fact that DHT sensor is very sensitive to timings.

But the situation is much worse with 100% CPU usage. Then it is not possible to read anything from the sensor at all. The polling always time outs regardless the set timeout. There should be about 40 events but there is always only 1 event in this case. Any ideas to improve this to get at least occasional readings?

I tried setting the thread to realtime priority but the result makes no difference. I also tried using Linux DHT kernel driver (which allows direct temperatur reading from /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_temp_input) but it behaves in the same way. It seems that the problem is not the polling itself - accidental data misses due to high latency, but rather that the kernel is not able to process GPIO interrupts at all when CPU usage is high.

Comment: How did you try to use the kernel driver? If you still try to read the GPIO pins, you aren't using the driver. The whole point of a kernel driver is that the entire operation of polling and reading will happen at the kernel level, at a higher priority than other code (except other kernel drivers).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you must create device tree overlay for dht sensor. Something like this https://github.com/eq-3/RaspberryMatic/blob/master/linux-4.1/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/dht11-overlay.dts but you must modify GPIO pins according to your board. Then you can read directly from /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_temp_input

Comment: If driver doesn’t support the buffering mode, it’s probably what worth to add.

Comment: Linux DHT driver can be found here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/iio/humidity/dht11.c
It works most of the time but results in "Only X signal edges detected" errors when CPU usage is high. It looks to me that it could happen if IRQ interrupt was missed.

Comment: In that case you need to have a dedicated CPU core for this task (seems like a huge overkill with waste of resources), or switch to RTOS from Linux. Or redesign hardware to use a microcontroller in between (usual way of solving this kind of issues with sensors).

Comment: @0andriy Thanks. It is what I have done in the past for similar problem on SPI bus. I set Linux kernel parameter isolcpus=3 and then set affinity for kernel "spi0" thread to this CPU and it fixed the problem. But how to do this with GPIO? There seems to be no thread that is responsible for watching for GPIO events.

Comment: There is kernel interrupt handler that will be monitoring the line for the events. You need to use IRQ affinity for it.